# iOS - 'val' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level(from my pod)

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

So i have built a pod and i am trying to use it in my project.
I have this data struct :

```
public struct Device {
  public init() {}

  var id: String = ""
  var serial: String = ""
  var account: String = ""
  var name: String = ""
  var isAttached: Bool?
  var isShared: Bool?
}
```

I have this func in the parser:

```
func getDevices(json: JSON) -> [Device] {
    var devices = [Device]()

    for device in json.arrayValue {
        var item = Device()
        item.account = device["account"].string!
        item.id = device["id"].string!
        item.isAttached = device["isAttached"].boolValue
        item.isShared = device["isShared"].boolValue
        item.name = device["name"].string!
        item.serial = device["serial"].string!
        devices.append(item)
    }
    return devices
}
```

and this method in the api class:

```
func getDevices( success: @escaping ([Device]) -> Void, failure: @escaping (String) -> Void) {

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer \(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "accessToken")!)",
        "X-Account-ID": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "accountToken")!
    ]

    Alamofire.request(Constants.Url.PENDING_DEVICE, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            let json = JSON(data)
            self.devices = self.helper.getDevices(json: json)
            success(self.devices)
        }

        if response.result.isFailure {
            print("status code is:\(String(describing: response.response?.statusCode))")
            let error : Error = response.result.error!
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            failure(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

yet when i use it in the project like so :

```
    self.requestManager.getDevice(success: { (devices) in
            for device in devices {
                var item = Device()
                item = device
                item.name //'name' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level error

        }
    }) { (error) in
        //
    }
```

in other struct i have created this works perfect , any ideas? i thought     public init() {}
 is the one to fix this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you build a pod separately and using it inside the framework then all the variables declared in the pod should be either `public` or `open`.

Example:

```
public struct Device {
  ...
  ...
  public var name: String = ""
  ...
}
```

`public` and `open` are for only framework writers, that means outside of the framework (there is no outside of the project :)).

> public - This can be used by objects outside my framework.
>
> open - public and objects outside my framework can subclass this.

Comment: The public init() not make sure that happens?

Comment: How would it? Public init makes init public. The end. It does not make name public. To make name public, declare public var name.